# Get total mean for variables nested in a list of lists of lists

Tags: r, tidyverse

Assume a list of lists which might e.g. represent markets over time periods. We have six periods and in each period the same three markets. For each market there might be a lot of variables. Here, we are interested in the  `profit`and `sales`. We want to calculate a mean value for each over all periods and all markets. 
Here is a toy data-set:

```
periods <- list()
markets <- list()

set.seed(11)
for (i in seq(1:6)) {
    for (j in seq(1:3)) {
        markets[[j]] <- list(profit =  sample(1:100, 1), sales =  sample(1:10, 1))
        }
    periods[[i]] <- markets
}
```

Here some actual data:

```
list(list(list(profit = 28L, sales = 1L), list(profit = 52L, 
    sales = 1L), list(profit = 7L, sales = 10L)), list(list(profit = 9L, 
    sales = 3L), list(profit = 89L, sales = 2L), list(profit = 18L, 
    sales = 5L)), list(list(profit = 91L, sales = 9L), list(profit = 74L, 
    sales = 6L), list(profit = 49L, sales = 4L)), list(list(profit = 16L, 
    sales = 5L), list(profit = 21L, sales = 7L), list(profit = 37L, 
    sales = 4L)), list(list(profit = 7L, sales = 5L), list(profit = 40L, 
    sales = 1L), list(profit = 13L, sales = 4L)), list(list(profit = 51L, 
    sales = 4L), list(profit = 42L, sales = 3L), list(profit = 82L, 
    sales = 7L)))
```

Expected output:

```
profit == 40,33
sales == 4,5
```

Now, I can achieve this using a loop. But I'd really like to see a more elegant solution. Preferably, with `tidyverse`. For a simple list of values I could use something like `periods %>% map('sales') %>% unlist() %>% mean()`. However, I have failed so far in this more complicated case.

Comment: Your expected output are two numbers, mean profits and mean sales?

Comment: yes, the expected output are two numbers. The total mean for `sales` over all periods and markets and the same for `profits`. It seems @Ronak Shah 's answer almost solves it, this is what I want: `periods %>% map_df(~tibble(profit = map_dbl(., pluck, "profit") %>% mean)) %>% unlist() %>% mean()`

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
df %>% 
   flatten() %>% 
   flatten() %>% 
   tibble(a=names(.), b=unlist(.)) %>% 
   group_by(a) %>% 
   summarise(Mean=mean(b))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  a       Mean
  <chr>  <dbl>
1 profit  40.3
2 sales    4.5
```

Or simply run

```
df %>% 
   reduce(bind_rows) %>% 
   summarise_all(mean)
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  profit sales
   <dbl> <dbl>
1   40.3   4.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could nicely create a matrix after unlisting and summarize this.

```
summary(matrix(unlist(periods), , 2, by=TRUE))
#       V1              V2       
# Min.   : 3.00   Min.   : 1.00  
# 1st Qu.:29.00   1st Qu.: 2.25  
# Median :46.50   Median : 4.00  
# Mean   :47.67   Mean   : 5.00  
# 3rd Qu.:67.50   3rd Qu.: 7.00  
# Max.   :89.00   Max.   :10.00  
summary(matrix(unlist(markets), , 2, by=TRUE))
#       V1              V2   
# Min.   :29.00   Min.   :4  
# 1st Qu.:44.50   1st Qu.:5  
# Median :60.00   Median :6  
# Mean   :56.33   Mean   :6  
# 3rd Qu.:70.00   3rd Qu.:7  
# Max.   :80.00   Max.   :8  

summary(matrix(unlist(list(periods, markets)), , 2, by=TRUE))
#       V1             V2        
# Min.   : 3.0   Min.   : 1.000  
# 1st Qu.:29.0   1st Qu.: 3.000  
# Median :48.0   Median : 4.000  
# Mean   :48.9   Mean   : 5.143  
# 3rd Qu.:70.0   3rd Qu.: 7.000  
# Max.   :89.0   Max.   :10.000
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use `map` to loop over every list in `periods` and select `"profit"` and `"sales"` column individually  and then take `mean` over it.

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  profit = map(periods, ~pluck(., 1) %>% flatten_dbl) %>% flatten_dbl %>% mean, 
  sales = map(periods, ~pluck(., 2) %>% flatten_dbl) %>% flatten_dbl %>% mean
 )

# A tibble: 1 x 2
#  profit sales
#   <dbl> <dbl>
#1   40.3   4.5
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I wanted. Is there a way to extract the "columns" (profit and sales) by index instead of by name? For example when I have many more variables per market and want to get the mean for all of them.

Comment: @mc51 Thank you for sharing the data. I have updated the answer by picking element based on index instead.

Comment: Your edited answer seems to be wrong. I get `profit = 19.08333` and `sales = 28.16667` with it.

Comment: @mc51 I am using the data which you shared using `dput`. I checked again, it gives me the expected output.

Comment: im pretty confident it is wrong. Because `map(periods, ~pluck(., 1) %>% flatten_dbl)` will give you a list of `sales` and `profits`. So you compute the mean of `sales` combined with `profits` which is not senseful

Comment: For me output of  `map(periods, ~pluck(., "profit") %>% flatten_dbl)` and 
`map(periods, ~pluck(., 1) %>% flatten_dbl)` is the same. Same goes for "sales".

Comment: Interesting. `map(periods, ~pluck(., 'profit'))` returns only NULLs for me! (dplyr   0.7.6)

Comment: are using your "actual data" which you have posted ? BTW you might want to upgrade the packages I have `packageVersion("dplyr")
#[1] 0.8.0.1` and `packageVersion("purrr")
[1] 0.3.2`

Comment: @mc51 ohh..I think I understood what might be the issue. In your actual dataset "profit" is not at position 1 and "sales" is not at position 2. You might want to change that index based on your actual data.